# Parameters in behat.yml

Tags: symfony, behat

I want to make

```
behat.yml -

default:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            base_url: 'my-url'
```

a parameter pulled from parameters.yml...  Is this possible?  I made a mink_base_url parameter in parameters.yml and then added

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
```

to behat.yml.  No matter what I do, I get this

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]                                
The service "behat.mink.context.initializer" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "mink_base_url"
```

Comment: I can't say thank you in my own post?  Wow...

Comment: "thanks", "help me" and other are considered fluf, as they don't add anything to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behat configuration is in no way related to Symfony's. It's true that Behat uses Symfony's DI container, but it's a separate instance.

If wanted to implement it, you'd probably need to create your own Behat extension to support the `imports` section.

Comment: Is there a way to get parameter from parameters.yml in FeatureContext constructor with behat3? (I'm using symfony2extension)

Comment: Assuming there is a Symfony parameter called `my-url`, you have to use `'%my-url%'` instead of `'my-url'`.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me with Symfony 3. Just omit `base_url` from `behat.yml`, and set it from the container parameters. Thanks to @DanielM for providing the hint.

```
<?php

use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class FeatureContext extends MinkContext {
    /**
     * FeatureContext constructor.
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     */
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * @BeforeScenario
     */
    public function setUpTestEnvironment()
    {
        $this->setMinkParameter('base_url', $this->container->getParameter('my_url'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to access the symfony parameters within behat yaml as using

`- '%%name_of_the_parameter%%'`

Double percentage sign (%%) does the trick.

Comment: I don't use symfony anymore, but thanks for adding this as it might be useful for others!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to access base_url, you can get it once mink has been started.

```
$this->getMinkParameter('base_url');
```

Here's an example :

```
class AbstractBehatContext extends MinkContext {

    /**
     * The base url as set behat.yml
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $baseUrl;

    /**
     * @BeforeScenario
     */
    public function getBaseUrl() {

        $this->baseUrl = $this->getMinkParameter('base_url');

    }

}
```

Note, this needs to be able to access Mink, so it won't work in `__construct` or in `@BeforeSuite`. Additionally `@BeforeScenario` will be called at the start of every scenario which is going to set it pointlessly a lot.