# How to inject Symfony param from parameters.yml into Behat 3 configuration?

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, behat

I need to set the `base_url` for `Behat\MinkExtension`.

Here is a part of my **app/config/parameters.yml**:

```
parameters:
    # ...
    behat_base_url: http://my-app.local/app_test.php
    # ...
```

Here is a part of my **behat.yml**:

```
frontend:
    gherkin:
        filters:
            tags: "@frontend"
    suites:
        javascript:
            mink_session: default
            mink_javascript_session: selenium2
            contexts:
                - FeatureContext: ~

    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url: http://my-app.local/app_test.php
            sessions:
                default:
                    symfony2: ~
                selenium2:
                    selenium2:
                        browser: chrome
                        capabilities:
                            extra_capabilities:
                                chromeOptions:
                                    args: ["--start-maximized"]
```

Can I do something like this (to provide reference to `parameters.behat_base_url`)

```
imports:
    - app/config/parameters.yml

# ...
extensions:
    Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
    Behat\MinkExtension:
        base_url: *parameters.behat_base_url # reference to value from parameters.yml
# ...
```

Or maybe exist another right and "true" way how I can set `base_url` from `parameters.yml` or another place. So, any developer will have his own configuration for test env.

Could you tell how you solve the issue with different test environment developer's configuration?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26427270/1220930

Comment: @Timurib thanks, I already saw this post. I hope somebody can say how to solve the issue with different test environment configuration. Of course, I can tell to devs: "Hey, guys, let's use domain http://my-app.my for Behat tests" but... it's ugly.

Also Behat3 supports  import. So maybe exists a way how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So. I found two solutions.

**The first**: use `BEHAT_PARAMS` to configure. for example:

Run in command line.

```
export BEHAT_PARAMS='{"extensions":{"Behat\\MinkExtension":{"base_url":"http://my-app.local/app_test.php"}}}'
```

Note: in that case it specify default params, so you should NOT define those parameters in `behat.yml` (becase they have higher priority and will be overwritten). You can read about it in [behat docs](http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/user_guide/configuration.html#environment-variable-behat-params)

But this case is not for me. I don't want developer each time configure the environment.

**The second**:

I specified following method in my `FeatureContext`:

```
/** @BeforeScenario */
public function beforeScenario(\Behat\Behat\Hook\Scope\BeforeScenarioScope $scenario)
{
    if ($scenario->getSuite()->getName() == 'javascript') {
        $this->setMinkParameter('base_url', $this->getContainer()->getParameter('behat_base_url'));
    }
}
```

So, before each scenario I check that the suite is `javascript` and set `base_url`. The value I get from `parameters.yml` using container.
Maybe it's a little bit "dirty" trick, but it works fine for me.

Get container you can from kernel. To inject kernel you should implement `Behat\Symfony2Extension\Context\KernelAwareContext` and add method `setKernel()`:

```
public function setKernel(KernelInterface $kernel)
{
    $this->kernel = $kernel;
}
```

So, I choose the second way.

If somebody know more elegant solution let me know.