# Add Behat\Symfony2Extension support to my behat suite

Tags: php, symfony, behat

I have a central Behat test suite codebase I use all throughout my companies projects. There is a ApiContext available which does curl calls using the curl lib from PHP itself but I really want to start supporting the Behat\Symfony2Extension in our Symfony projects as well so I don't have to setup nginx to listen to create a vhost to call those curl calls to.

I am a Symfony n00b and I'm not sure how to do this. I've setup the extension but the problem here (I think) is the use of curl in this case.

Maybe someone of you could help me get an idea of what I can do to fix this. I still want to support this lib with external calls as it is used in other projects too.

Comment: If you need yml config file example check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40798687/how-to-inject-symfony-param-from-parameters-yml-into-behat-3-configuration

Comment: Have you ever seen examples here? http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/posts/behat